# 2D allocated array (fixed number of columns) as return value of a function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I would like some help with pointers:
in main function I have initialized variable that should point to the array:

```
int main() {

int n;
double (*array)[3];
array = fillArray(&n);
```

The function receives an integer argument, which counts number of rows. The return value of the function should be a pointer to the newly created array, which will be saved to the variable 'array' in main function:

```
double (*)[3] fillArray(int * n) {
    double (*array)[3] = NULL;
    int allocated = 0;
    *n = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        /*scanning input*/

        if (allocated <= *n)
        {
        allocated += 10;
        array = (double(*)[3]) realloc (array, sizeof(*array) * allocated)
        }
        array[*n][0] = value1;
        array[*n][1] = value2;
        array[*n][2] = value3;
        (*n)++;
    }
    return array;
}
```

However, the type of return value isn't right and I am kinda lost. Can anyone tell me what is wrong in this code?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: explain "the type of return value isn't right ", what error are you getting?

Comment: Compiling errors: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token and error: expected initializer before ‘fillArray’

Comment: What kind of type do you think a `double (*)[3]` is?

Comment: Shouldn't it be the 2D array?

Comment: @Mirelle, technically, `double (*)[3]` is a pointer to an array of 3 `double`s, which might or might not be the first element of a 2D array of `double`s.  It *is* the type that a 2D array of `double` will decay to if its second dimension is 3.  And it is, to be sure, a valid type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has an unrelated syntax error and some undeclared variables, but the problem you asked about has to do with the form of the declaration of function `fillArray()`.  This alternative works for me:

```
double (*fillArray(int * n))[3] {
    double (*array)[3] = NULL;

    /* ... */

    return array;
}
```

Note the similarity in form to the declarations of your variables of the same type.

The problem is that although `double (*)[3]` is a perfectly valid type designator for use, say, in a cast, it is incorrect to use it quite as you tried to do to *declare* the type of an object.

Comment: I see, so I should just pass the whole array as an argument to the function? Would that be a better solution? The code you posted doesn't work for me.. and I don't really understand how you dereferenced.. a function? I am sorry I am still a newbie to C so..

Comment: @mireille, you can read the declaration as saying "fillValue is a function accepting one argument of type `int *`; dereferencing *its return value* yields an array of 3 `double`s."  As I pointed out, the form is quite parallel to that of your variable declarations.

Comment: @mireille, since inside your function you (re)allocate space for the pointer to point to, it would not be sufficient to pass your pointer as an argument.  You would need to pass a pointer to the pointer, for the same reason that you now pass a pointer to the `int`.  I think you're already dealing with enough type complexity -- and admirably so for a self-proclaimed newbie, if I may say so.  Do make sure you've copied my declaration correctly, and if you're still getting errors then make sure that they don't refer to something else.

Comment: Think of it this way: you can replace a variable name with a function name and parameter list, and you'll get a function returning that type, instead of a variable. `int (*array_ptr)[3]` -> `int (*foo(int *n))[3]` by replacing `array_ptr` with `foo(int *n)` (Likewise, you get the array pointer in the first place by replacing `array` with `(*array_ptr)` in `int array[3];`)

Answer (score 1):

given some guessing about items not mentioned in the question.

I think this is what you are looking for.

Notice the checking for success of the call to `realloc()`

Notice the #define of the `magic` numbers

```
#include <stdlib.h> // realloc(), exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

#define ALLOCATION_INCREMENT (10)
#define NUM_DOUBLES (3)

struct tagArray
{
    double arrayEntry[ NUM_DOUBLES ];
};

struct tagArray *fillArray(int *n);

int main( void )
{

    int n = 0;
    struct tagArray *array;

    if( NULL == (array = fillArray(&n) ) )
    { // then array generation failed
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, array generation successful

    ....

    free( array );
    return 0;    
} // end function: main


struct tagArray *fillArray(int *n)
{
    struct tagArray *array = NULL;
    int allocated =0;

    while( 1 )
    {
        /* scanning input,
         * to acquire 'value1, value2, value3'
         * with some key input causes execution of 'break;'
         * */

        if( allocated <= *n )
        {
            allocated += ALLOCATION_INCREMENT;
            struct tagArray *temp = realloc (array, sizeof( struct tagArray) * allocated );

            if( !temp )
            { // then realloc failed
                free( array );
                return( NULL );
            }

            array = temp;
        }

        array[*n][0] = value1;
        array[*n][1] = value2;
        array[*n][2] = value3;
        (*n)++;
    }

    return array;
} // end function: fillArray
```